# How can you search for files in Azure with Visual Studio Cloud Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure website published, and I want to examine some files.  Using VS2015's Cloud Explorer, I have to navigate to find my file:

```
MyAzureResourceGroup
    App Services
        MyAzureWebsite
            Files
                File1
                File2
                ....
```

This is a real pain in the neck.  Especially once you get down to the "Files" part, you then keep having to hit "Load More" if your file doesn't appear.

So given the above structure, and I know there is a file named **File2** is there  a quick way of finding it in Cloud Explorer and/or opening it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use KUDU to navigate around your Azure Web Apps file structure. You can download, edit there as well apart from great deal more things. You can go to KUDU by 2 ways.

**Method 01**

Use the *Azure Portal* and navigate to your Azure Web App and then in the *Development Tools* section click on *Advanced Tools* and then on ***Go*** link. Look at the screenshot below,

[image]

**Method 02**

You can also add scm to the middle of your Web App URL and navigate to KUDU. For example, if your Web Site URL is

> https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net

you can change it to

> https://mywebsite.*scm*.azurewebsites.net

and this will take you to the KUDU site. You have to login with your Microsoft Account to authenticate.

After login in to KUDU website, in the menu do to Debug Console and Click on CMD link.

[image]

This will give you a command prompt where you can navigate the file structure either by DOS commands or clicking on the file tree links. You can edit files, download files, delete files here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, if you just want to easily locate to the special file in the could explorer. I suggest you could use its search box.

Like below:

[image]

In the search box, if you want to locate the file2, you could try below format.

```
/{your subsurscriptions name}/{the web service rescource group name}/{web service name}/Files/File2
```

Then you could right click the file and click 'open' to open the file in the VS.